# Is this C# code secure for RSA encryption of Classified data?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I will be encrypting CLASSIFIED data and my data must be secured with the most advanced encryption available. I am encrypting the data with AES and the key with RSA. My RSA code is below. Please confirm if this code is secure:

```
  static class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(3072);
      var privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
      var pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);
      string pubKeyString;
      {
        var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        xs.Serialize(sw, pubKey);
        pubKeyString = sw.ToString();
      }
  {
    //get a stream from the string
    var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(pubKeyString);
    //we need a deserializer
    var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
    //get the object back from the stream
    pubKey = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr);
  }
  csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
  csp.ImportParameters(pubKey);
  var plainTextData = "foobar";
  var bytesPlainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainTextData);
  var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(bytesPlainTextData, false);
  var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesCypherText);
  bytesCypherText = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);
  csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
  csp.ImportParameters(privKey);
  bytesPlainTextData = csp.Decrypt(bytesCypherText, false);
  plainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesPlainTextData);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is very messy. What's with the random blocks like where you have `//get a stream from the string`?

Comment: The second parameter of `rsa.Encrypt` stands for "use secure padding", you set it to `false`.

Comment: You're claiming that you use this to encrypt AES keys, yet you have a UTF-16 string as plaintext. That doesn't match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't specify which government authority you fall under, so I will assume the US DoD.

This encryption scheme will **not** satisfy any US DoD data security requirements except for data classified at "confidential" or under a special classification that has "confidential" restrictions with compartmentalization (or UCI with the same *effective restrictions*).

This is primarily because you're not using an approved encryption scheme that protects data integrity, provides tamper evidence, and includes an approved symmetric cipher. You're also preventing OAEP padding during your RSA encryption call, something that has been required for quite some time now.

But your question is also incorrect. "Classified data" is a thing and not really a level of security. Data has a classification, so do processes and the data involved in those processes. Classification is an iterative process to determine the security requirements for data based on their value, the threat model for all involved systems, and the total impact of loss, theft, or modification of the data in transit or storage.

To make your scheme correct, I advise you do the following:

- Generate key pairs for all parties that need to exchange data with each other
- Before exchanging data, generate a random 256-bit value to be used as a key
- Encrypt the 256-bit key value with the destination party's public key and digitally sign that result with the sender's private key
- Encrypt your data using AES-256-ICM with key value, digitally sign the result
- Transmit the result of the last two operations to the destination
- The destination verifies the signatures of both the encrypted key and the encrypted data
- The destination decrypts the key and uses that key to decrypt the data
- The destination now has the decrypted data

This above scheme technically would satisfy the **basic** encryption requirements for "top secret" classified information under the US DoD manual for information security standards.

There's more to it in terms of storage, code review, certifiable relaibility, etc etc. There's a huge review process and it's extremely involved. It's not something an independent developer will be able to accomplish easily.

On a final note, you state you are encrypting classified data and I assume you are not a specialist in information security or cryptography. It is recommended and required in some cases that you hire a subject matter expert for the architectural process. In the US, you can face fines or jail time (in negligence cases) if you don't follow the approved processes for developing software handling sensitive information of **any** kind. But more than that, nobody is likely to accept your software without a comprehensive code review and more than likely they won't accept C# code because there's not enough validation for the associated runtimes, unless you're using a custom one. You're stuck with C, C++, or Java (rare) most of the time in the sensitive data world of the US government.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I **am** using rijndael (256) to encrypt the message and then I am using this code to encrypt the key. is there anything wrong with this code itself? BTW it's SECRET not TOP SECRET

Comment: @javaseaayameradost Yes. You're not using OAEP during your RSA encrypt call, you actually disable it. The runtime also doesn't hold a FIPS certificate so it's pretty useless for classified data in the US. Why not use AES-256-GCM instead of doing this the hard way?

Comment: Since you edited your comment stating you're dealing in the "secret" classification and didn't correct me on the country, I'd advise that you speak with your manager and ask for an expert in cryptography to guide you. Your product will be more secure in the end and the liability will be off of your shoulders.

Comment: the files encrypted are not for the government. I am using the confidentiality level SECRET as a reference and the files encrypted with this application have nothing to do with the government. how do i use AES-256-GCM?

Comment: Google it and ask a specific question when you've tried using it with C# and .NET. Also saying you're using the level secret as a reference is silly, since it has a huge amount of overhead and restrictions that are generally unnecessary for all but the largest institutions that need to cover massive amounts of data. Process comes with size and you seem to be over engineering your process if you aren't dealing with a government entity. Just stick with a standard library that does everything for you, it's easier. Check out https://github.com/adamcaudill/libsodium-net for an easy to use library.

Comment: @Micheal "[confidentiality level secret] has a huge amount of overhead and restrictions that are generally unnecessary for all but the largest institutions that need to cover massive amounts of data." that's **exactly** why i referred to 'secret'. I **WANT** those unnecessary restrictions